# Javascript generation of html inputs

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
    <form action="insertquestion.php" method="POST">
        <script>
            function xyz(){
                var str="answer";
                var str1=1;
                for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    var str3 = str+str1;
                    document.write('<input type=text name=str3 />');
                    str1++;
                }
            }
            xyz();
        </script>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

I wanted the name attribute of the input text to be of the form `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4`, `answer5` to be generated automatically but name attribute of all the input feilds are showing the constant value `str3`.

How to include html in javascript?

Comment: `document.write('<input type=text name=' + str3  + '/>');`

Comment: It is not recommended to create HTML in JavaScript. Instead copy/clone one element from the page, change its attributes and insert it in the Document.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your inputs name to the same value instead of concatenating this name from variables.

Also `str`, `str1` and `str3` variables are in fact not needed to do it, and your code can be simplified.

So your generation function could look like:

```
function xyz(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        document.write('<input type=text name="answer' + i + '" />');
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, or even simpler, you dont need `var str = "answer"` and you can just put `document.write('<input type="text" name="answer' + i + '" />');`

Comment: @indubitablee Yeah, surely. Missed that originally.

Comment: @Salveru You are welcome. Consider [marking answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) just instead of "thank you" if answer was helpful. It will also help others having similar question to find correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

```css
label{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<form action="insertquestion.php" method="POST">
    <script>
    function xyz(){
        var str="answer";
        
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            document.write('<label>Answer ' + i + ': </label><input type=text name="answer' + i +'" /><br><br>');
        }
    }
    xyz();
    </script>
    <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Close this issue, please!